# Can you do a SOQL Query on a Hierarchical Custom Setting?

Tags: soql, customsetting

I have a Hierarchical Custom Setting that I need to SOQL use a SOQL query for using the current User's Profile.

Currently I'm using the getInstance() method with the User Profile ID to get the custom setting, then I update a field on it.  The problem is that it frequently errors with the Unable_to_lock_row error.

I want to try using a SOQL and the FOR UPDATE to try to prevent this error from happening.

Comment: Have a look at using the workbench (workbench.developerforce.com) to view the sobjects and develop soql/sosl statements - you'll see your custom setting in there. This way you can see what fields are available and try out difference queries without having to code. More info here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, the custom setting is an object just like other custom objects. So you can do the following SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Your_Setting__c Where SetupOwnerId = :profileId FOR UPDATE
```

If you're looking for the default setting, replace :profileId with UserInfo.getOrganizationId()

Comment: Thank you.  What I was missing / didn't know was how to query for the profile id.

Comment: If you're looking for the default setting, replace :profileId with User.getOrganizationId()

Comment: thanks James. Will update my answer with your comment if you don't mind.

Comment: Humble Correction - It is 'UserInfo.getOrganizationId()'.

Comment: Of course, using a query means you'll be using a governor limit, so use it sparingly.